# Why is the childNodes count is greater than expected?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a question about DOM. Consider the following javascript code, the output will be 5.

```
<body>
    <p>Hello</p>
<script>
    function countBody() {
        var childs = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes;
        alert(childs.length);
    }
    window.onload = countBody;
</script>
</body>
```

Since I have two element nodes and two text nodes, what is the 5th node?

Comment: I count five childNodes: the whitespace before the `<p>`, the `<p>` itself, the whitespace between it and the `<script>`, the script, and the whitespace after the script.

Comment: Why not write the additional code to iterate through the nodes and log their types and contents?

Comment: Loop over the children and see..... `for( var i=0; i<childs.length; i++) console.log(childs[i])`

Comment: BTW, you can get the number of just element (not text) children by requesting the node object's  `.childElementCount` property, which I would expect to be 2 in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You have three text nodes.

- Between the body start tag and the paragraph.
- Between the paragraph and the script.
- Between the script and the body end tag

… you could loop over `childNodes` and `console.log()` each value to see.

Answer (score 0):

Just check it for yourself:

```html
<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <script>
      function countBody() {
          var childs = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes;
          console.log([].map.call(childs, function (node) { return node.textContent; }));
      }
      window.onload = countBody;
  </script>
</body>
```

You have missed one text node in your counting. Please be aware that output from snippet will be different from code you have provided.